# try-with-resource not closing socket connection

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

I am using Java 1.8, Although try-with-resource working fine in other parts of the application but in one class where I have written like this :

```
try(Socket sock = socket != null ? socket : new Socket()){ //Other implementation}
```

It says resource leak. Any clue ?

Comment: this is a message from the compiler of the IDE (eclipse?) it sometimes reports false positives

Comment: I understand from the message, there is an option to Socket couldn't initialize if socket is not null and not assigned object cannot close.

Comment: My eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) does not complain it.

Comment: @haticeSigirci You are right, Is there anyway to handle this case. I want to close Socket object

Comment: Move the ternary operator into a function that takes `socket` as a param and performs this logic. That will avoid the compiler being confused by the ternary operator here.

Comment: Also, please put your code in your question as text, not an image.

Comment: Can you try this: try(Socket sock = (socket != null ? socket : new Socket())){

Comment: @Abhishek Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the message, there is an option to Socket couldn't initialize if socket is not null and not assigned object cannot close.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn this is so out of place for so many reasons. For example: What makes you think the poster is not a woman?

Comment: How could it not be assigned?

Comment: @LonelyNeuron My bad. `not assigned object cannot close.` -> this is evaluated after boolean expression

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn don't do this again any women

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in principle no problem so the warning that Eclipse gives can be ignored.

However, your code would be much clearer if you wrote it like this:

```
if(null != socket){
    try(Socket sock =  new Socket()){

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```